# "C Compiler not working" While building trying to build VLC in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, vlc

Here is part of my compilation result:

===============================================================================

```
You are ready to build VLC and its contribs
make: '.gas' is up to date.
[info] Building contrib for iOS in '/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/iPhoneOS-arm64'
[info] LD FLAGS SELECTED = '-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/lib -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=5.1'
/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc
error: invalid deployment target '5.1.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires
      '7.0.0' or later)
1 error generated.
make: Nothing to be done for `fetch'.
error: invalid deployment target '5.1.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires
      '7.0.0' or later)
1 error generated.
sed -i.orig s/-ansi// freetype/builds/unix/configure
cd freetype && GNUMAKE=make CC="xcrun clang" CXX="xcrun clang++" LD="xcrun ld" AR="xcrun ar" CCAS="gas-preprocessor.pl xcrun clang -c" RANLIB="xcrun ranlib" STRIP="xcrun strip" PATH="/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/arm-apple-darwin11-arm64/bin:/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin:/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin:/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/arm-apple-darwin11/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin" CPPFLAGS="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -O3 -g -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -O3 -g -I/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/arm-apple-darwin11-arm64/include" CFLAGS="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -O3 -g -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -O3 -g -I/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/arm-apple-darwin11-arm64/include -g" CXXFLAGS="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -O3 -g -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -O3 -g -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -O3 -g -I/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/arm-apple-darwin11-arm64/include -g -I/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/arm-apple-darwin11-arm64/include -g" LDFLAGS="-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/lib -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/lib -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -L/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/arm-apple-darwin11-arm64/lib" ./configure --without-png --prefix="/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/arm-apple-darwin11-arm64" --build="arm-apple-darwin11" --host="x86_64-apple-darwin11" --target="x86_64-apple-darwin11" --program-prefix="" --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking --with-pic
FreeType build system -- automatic system detection
The following settings are used:
  platform                    unix
  compiler                    xcrun clang
  configuration directory     ./builds/unix
  configuration rules         ./builds/unix/unix.mk
If this does not correspond to your system or settings please remove the file
`config.mk' from this directory then read the INSTALL file for help.
Otherwise, simply type `make' again to build the library,
or `make refdoc' to build the API reference (the latter needs python).
cd builds/unix; /bin/sh ./configure  '--without-png' '--prefix=/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/arm-apple-darwin11-arm64' '--build=arm-apple-darwin11' '--host=x86_64-apple-darwin11' '--target=x86_64-apple-darwin11' '--program-prefix=' '--enable-static' '--disable-shared' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--with-pic'
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-dependency-tracking
checking build system type... arm-apple-darwin11
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11
checking for x86_64-apple-darwin11-gcc... xcrun clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/nikhil.t/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/iPhoneOS-arm64/freetype/builds/unix':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

make[1]: *** [setup] Error 77

make: *** [.freetype2] Error 2
```

===================================================================

I am using guideline provided by [VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/iOSCompile)

I tried to change the xcrun path in `build.sh` `(ImportedSources/vlc/extras/package/ios/build.sh)` but it resets to original once I build the script.

**Is there another way I could change this, so that c compiler works for me?**
I am stuck on this for the last 9 days, please provide some guidance.

Thanks,

Albin.K.J

Answer (score 1):

The first error is:

`error: invalid deployment target '5.1.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires
      '7.0.0' or later)`

... so I would suggest trying what it suggests: bumping the deployment target up from 5.1.0 to 7.0.0, or remove arm64 support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my real issue is c compiler not working.

Answer (score 1):

May be wrong compiler path.

Check the CC points to the correct path also it is as expected in the script file.

I also have the same issue, setting CC correctly did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

The required compilers are missing from your system. You need both a C++ compiler and a C compiler.

You can install the compilers (GCC and G++) using `apt-get install gcc g++`.